# Discord.js | How to get members currently connected to a Voice Channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the members who are currently connected to a specific voice channel. With some properties I could get them, but the problem I found was that the members who are listed aren't the ones who are currently connected but the ones who had been connected to the voice channel when the bot started running.

This is my code (it's shortened but is copied):

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] })
client.on('messageCreate', messagesHandler)

function messagesHandler (msg) {
  if (msg.author.bot) return false;
  console.log(`Msg received: ${msg.content}`)

  if (msg.content.startsWith('/')) {
    const msgArr = msg.content.split(' ')

    switch (msgArr[0]) {
      case '/list':
        listCommand(msg, msgArr)
        break
    }
  }
}

async function listCommand (msg, msgArr) {
  if(!msgArr[1]) {
    const voiceChannel = await getChannel(msg, 'Voice1', true).fetch()
    if (!voiceChannel) {
      msg.channel.send('ERROR: Voice1 channel not found')
    } else {
      await getCurrentChannelMembers(msg, voiceChannel)
    }
  }
}

function getChannel(msg, channel, voiceChannel = false) {
  return msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === channel && (!voiceChannel || c.isVoice()))
}

async function getCurrentChannelMembers (msg, channel) {
  const fetchedChannel = await channel.fetch(true)
  const members = fetchedChannel.members
  console.log('Members: ', members)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works. You are probably missing a permission or intent. Try adding all voice related intents to your bot and see if it works that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bot needs `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent

```js
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
  ] 
})
```